ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'toolkit'
I keep getting import error. My file structure is as below.
-- agents
  -- __init__.py
  -- main.py
-- toolkit
  -- __init__.py
  -- tools.py

I keep getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'toolkit'
When importing I am using below code in main.py
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from langchain_core.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain_core.tools import Tool
from langchain.agents import(
    create_react_agent,
    AgentExecutor,
)
from langchain import hub

from toolkit import tools


def lookup(name: str) -> str:
  
  llm = ChatOpenAI(
    temperature=0,
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo"
  )  
  
  template = """given the full name {name_of_person} I want you to get me a link to their LinkedIn profile page.
  your answer should only contain a URL"""
  
  prompt_template = PromptTemplate(template=template, input_variables=["name_of_person"])
  
  tools_for_agent = [
    Tool(
        name="Crawl Google 4 linkedin profile page",
        func=tools.get_profile_url_tavily,
        description="useful when you need to get the LinkedIn URL"
    )
  ]
  
  react_prompt = hub.pull("hwchase17/react")
  agent = create_react_agent(llm=llm, tools=tools_for_agent, prompt=react_prompt)
  agent_executor = AgentExecutor(agent=agent, tools=tools_for_agent, verbose=True)
  
  result = agent_executor.invoke(
    input={"input": prompt_template.format_prompt(name_of_person=name)}
  )
  
  linked_profile_url = result["output"]
  return linked_profile_url


if __name__ == "__main__":
  linkedin_url = lookup(name="Bill Gates")
  print(linkedin_url)

Expecting the agent_executor to run but get below error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'toolkit'

I think the formatting of the file structure got a little messed up in the post. I think you're saying it looks like this but correct me if I'm wrong:

agents

__init__.py
main.py


toolkit

__init__.py
tools.py



If this is the case, then you need to change from toolkit import tools to from ..toolkit import tools since toolkit would be up a directory from main.py.

yes that is the structure and I tried using from ..toolkit import tools but still got the error. I was finally able to correct it by adding relative path
import sys
sys.path.append("../root-folder")
and that worked!

Guys I found the solution by looking at this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ad-inC3mJfU
I added following code and was able to import the toolkit module -
import sys
sys.path.append("../root-folder")
